# How to print a string if all values in an array are the same

Tags: java

I have an array that holds numbers:

```
int tarningar[] = new int[5];
```

When all the numbers are the same, I want to print "OK", e.g. with something like `system.out.println('ok');`. I have tried `if(tarningar[1] == tarningar[2] && tarningar[3] == tarningar[4])`, but then I am missing `tarningar[0]`.

How can I do this?

Comment: besides missing `tarningar[0]` that also doesn't check if all the elements are the same - it only checks if elements 1 and 2 are the same and elements 3 and 4 are the same. `{ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 }` would pass that test.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
boolean flag = true;
int first = tarningar[0];
for(int i = 1; i < 5 && flag; i++)
{
  if (tarningar[i] != first) flag = false;
}
if (flag) System.out.println("ok");
```

Comment: You ought to `break` if the flag goes false - or add it to the loop condition.

Comment: You can improve it by adding `&& flag` after `i < 5`.

Answer (score 23):

```
public class EqualArrayTest {

    public static boolean isAllEqual(int[] a){
        for(int i=1; i<a.length; i++){
            if(a[0] != a[i]){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(isAllEqual(new int[]{2,2,2}));
        System.out.println(isAllEqual(new int[]{2,2,1}));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's a more succinct Java 8 streams example:

```
Arrays.stream(tarningar).distinct().count() == 1
```

Answer (score 10):

with Google's Guava:

```
boolean allEqual = Sets.newHashSet(Ints.asList(tarningar)).size() == 1;
```

Answer (score 7):

*All values are the same* is equivalent to *All values are equal to any selected value*.

So just choose one as a *reference* and compare this chosen value to all other values.

Answer (score 5):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Don't take it serious.
 * But it works.
 */
public class Demo {

    public static boolean isAllSame(int... numbers) {
        int[] firstItemArray = new int[numbers.length];         
        Arrays.fill(firstItemArray, numbers[0]);

        return Arrays.equals(numbers, firstItemArray);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isAllSame(1,1,1,1));
        System.out.println(isAllSame(1,1,1,2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean isSame = true;

for(int i = 1; i < tarningar.length; i++) {
    if (tarningar[i] != tarningar[0]) {
        isSame = false;
    }
}

if (isSame) {
    System.out.println("OK");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 with the stream API:

```
Set<Integer> uniqueValues = Arrays.stream(tarningar)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
boolean allEqual = uniqueValues.size() == 1;
```

If you used `Integer[]` instead of `int[]` the following is supported in Java 7 and before:

```
// Integer[] tarninagr = ...
Set<Integer> uniqueValues = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(tarningar));
boolean allEqual = uniqueValues.size() == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution without a loop (and a fixed array length of 5):

```
int v = tarningar[0];

if (tarningar[1] == v && tarningar[2] == v && tarningar[3] == v && tarningar[4] == v) {
    System.out.println("All the same!");
}
```