# Check values in a list are all identical

Tags: coldfusion

Ok here's a thing, I have a form which when submitted can only update a table when a particular checkbox form variable values are identical, if one is different then it should proceed to update the table. So basically the user is selecting different rows and hitting the submit button.

So for example a good submission would be

```
form.claimid = 12,12,12,12,12
```

a bad submission would be

```
 form.claimid = 1,5,77,33,4,
```

I'm not sure how to check in a list if all the values in the form.claimid list  are identical or not?

I would appreciate any ideas on this.

Comment: Actually I have thought about this a bit more. I could loop through the list and use the compare function for each value.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448698/java-array-if-all-the-same) on some options on how to do this.

Comment: cflib.org has a ListDistinct function.  It would enable you to compare the actual list to a distinct list.

Comment: @Dan, totally forgot but CF 10 has a native ListRemoveDuplicates to serve exactly that purpose.

Comment: For next time, it is a good idea to check the [Functions By Category](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6a42) docs first. Just looking at the function names, at least three possibility comes to mind ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use CF's native ListRemoveDuplicates() if the version is sufficient (CF10, Railo/Lucee 4)

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ListRemoveDuplicates

```
<cfif ListLen(ListRemoveDuplicates(mylist)) eq 1>
```

---

I'll leave this as an alternate means for older CFs.

> I'm not sure how to check in a list if all the values in the form.claimid list are identical or not?

There are a couple ways, most of which involve looping, but I'm going to show you a regular expression that can do this. We're going to get the first value using ListFirst, and use a ReReplace on that value to see if every other value matches.

I use a loop here but only as a demonstration.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfset mylist = "11,22,33,44|44,44,33,44|557,557,557">
<cfloop list="#mylist#" index="m" delimiters="|">
  <cfset matchele = listfirst(m)>
  <cfset eradicate = rereplace(m,"(?:(?:^|,)#matchele#(?=,|$))+","","ALL")>
  "#m#", "#matchele#", "#eradicate#"<br />
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: many thanks for your answers, I tried your code and added some bits so that I can see whats happening. I'm a little confused on what is happening, the first set of numbers seems to work fine, the second set is throwing me a bit as it is showing to eradicate 33 and 44, I would have thought it would leave 44 in. The last one shows  to eradicate 557 even though all of the numbers are identical, that one has really thrown me not unless im missing something here.

Comment: @JeepersCreepers It's working on cflive.net. I updated the output line to reflect the current sublist and quote each value so that it's more legible with such simple output. For instance, the 557 line should now read `"557,557,557", "557", ""`

Comment: How would the ListRemoveDuplicates() work if I wanted to check for non duplicate values?

Comment: As I demonstrated at the start of my answer: `<cfif ListLen(ListRemoveDuplicates(mylist)) eq 1>` means that there's only one unique value in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck on CF 9 or lower, you could loop over the list and put the elements into a `struct`:

```
<cfset list_coll = structNew() />
<cfloop list="#mylist#" index="myitem">
    <cfset list_coll[myitem] = "dummy" />
</cfloop>
<cfif structCount(list_coll) EQ 1>
    <!--- This is good --->
<cfelse>
    <!--- This is bad --->
</cfif>
```

The reason this works is that `struct`s can't have duplicate keys.